# MS Access: Condition in WHERE clause (defaults to use if parameter is null)

Tags: ms-access, parameters, where-clause

I need a parametrized crosstab query. I mostly worked it out except for parameters part.
I have four parameters to apply: ChangeID and variant1, variant2 and variant3.
ChangeID is mandatory, it needs to be filled in by the user. Variant1..3 are optional: either user fills one to three variants or (if variant1 is null) the default should be used.

Default is an alternative of predefined variants, actual filled in variants should be applied as alternative too.

I thought of something like this:

```
PARAMETERS ChangeID Text (7), variant1 Text (10), variant2 Text (10), variant3 Text (10);
TRANSFORM Sum([Qty]*[inout]) AS QtyInOut
SELECT MatByOrder.CHpoint, MatByOrder.PN, MatByOrder.Description, MatByOrder.Price, MatByOrder.UoM
FROM Variants INNER JOIN MatByOrder ON Variants.BO = MatByOrder.BO

WHERE 
    (MatByOrder.CHpoint=ChangeID) AND 
    (IIF(isNull([variant1]); 
        (Variants.Variant="B100") OR (Variants.Variant="B200") OR (Variants.Variant="B300") OR (Variants.Variant="B400") OR (Variants.Variant="B500");
        (Variants.Variant=[variant1]) OR (Variants.Variant=[variant2]) OR (Variants.Variant=[variant3])
       )
    )

GROUP BY MatByOrder.CHpoint, MatByOrder.PN, MatByOrder.Description, MatByOrder.Price, MatByOrder.UoM
```

but it doesn't work. The problem is of course in IIF in WHERE clause.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: As an additional twist: it would do to apply two parameters: ChangeID and VariantString. The latter would be comma-separated variant list to apply as filter. Problem: this comma-separated list would have to be changed from "VARIANT1,VARIANT2,VARIANT3" to "VARIANT1 OR VARIANT2 OR VARIANT3" and then parsed from a string to actual alternative in second part of WHERE clause. Also, if VariantString is null the aforementioned default should be used. Is it possible?

Comment: Where are you doing this? Is building the SQL with VBA an option for you? It will give you a much better level of control.

Comment: I agree. Still I'd like to have a clickable object to call this query. In my DB I have multitude of utility tables, queries and forms and I distinguish significant ones by creating macros that run them and then pinning them to a ribbon I've created. 

How could I put a VBA routine as ribbon element?

Comment: You can build a query with VBA and you can call a function from a ribbon. However, it looks to me that you may need a form for this query to ensure valid input.

Comment: In your SQL statement, [variant1] [variant2] and [variant3] are not filtering any field. It seems erroneous. And ("B100" OR "B200" OR "B300" OR "B400" OR "B500") also looks like an erroneous criteria. can you fix or explain ? We need to understand how both Variant parameters and default values should be applied.

Comment: The query works on two tables: MatByOrder and Variants. You can see the fields of MatByOrder in SELECT clause. Variants has 3 fields: ID, BO and Variant... and gosh! yes, I've omitted "Variants.Variant=Variant1" etc. I've corrected it above. Even after the change, SQL is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WHERE 
    (MatByOrder.CHpoint=ChangeID) AND 
    (
       ( ([variant1] IS NULL) AND (Variants.Variant IN ('B200', 'B300', 'B400', 'B500')) )
       OR    
       ( ([variant1] IS NOT NULL) AND (Variants.Variant IN ([variant1], [variant2], [variant3])) )
    )
```

Comment: That's it! And I must add it's beautiful in its clarity. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the idea of Instr in my locale where comma is the parameter delimiter and it works for me. I think you should try the idea with plain query and see how it suits.

The idea is :

```
Instr(Nz(Var,String) & ",",Field & ",")>0
```

The addition of a comma or other delimiter to the field is important to avoid false matches.

```
PARAMETERS ChangeID Text (7), variant1 Text (10), variant2 Text (10), variant3 Text (10);
TRANSFORM Sum([Qty]*[inout]) AS QtyInOut
SELECT MatByOrder.CHpoint, MatByOrder.PN, MatByOrder.Description, MatByOrder.Price, MatByOrder.UoM
FROM Variants INNER JOIN MatByOrder ON Variants.BO = MatByOrder.BO

WHERE 
    (MatByOrder.CHpoint=ChangeID) AND 
    (Instr(Nz([variant1],"B100,B200,B300,B400,B500" 
               & [variant1] & "," & [variant2] & "," 
               & [variant3]) & ",", MatByOrder.CHpoint) > 0
    )

GROUP BY MatByOrder.CHpoint, MatByOrder.PN, MatByOrder.Description, MatByOrder.Price, MatByOrder.UoM
```